# Send windows credentials to a websocket (WebSockets4Net)

Tags: wpf, wcf, iis, websocket, windows-authentication

**Update**

We are using WebSockets4Net and it does nor work with Windows Authentication. From our investigation the only way to get Windows Authentication to work with WebSockets4Net is to rewrite the handshake, which was overkill.

To fix this we created a separate web socket implementation. Windows 8 and higher we use the default MS WebSocket Client and just set SendDefaultCredentials = true. On older clients we dropped support for Windows Authentication in our application.

**End Update**

We have a client requirement to have Windows Authentication turned on for all IIS servers and anonymous access off.

Our WCF REST endpoint connects just fine when Windows Authentication is on and Anonymous access is off.

The WebSocket connection attempt always returns a 401 unauthorized. During the handshake it does not send any windows credentials through.

The client is a WPF application using WebSockets4Net. I have posted a question on their project page asking the same question.

I can add any headers I may need in the client request, I just don't know what I am supposed to send. I am assuming something similar to:

```
Authorization: Negotiate Base64CredentialsGoHere
```

but my attempts to get that working have failed.

Here is the request header (from fiddler):

```
GET /patchis/DispatchSystem.svc/DispatchWebSocket HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: NzkwMTk3ZDctNzYzNy00NQ==
Host: server.company.com
Origin: ws://server.company.com
```

Here is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 15:51:23 GMT
Content-Length: 6069
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

I've changed the binding the following and verified that it works with MS Websockets implementation. We have to support windows 7 so we cannot use the .Net code.:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="customWebSocket">
      <byteStreamMessageEncoding />
      <httpsTransport maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" maxBufferSize="6553600" authenticationScheme="Negotiate">
        <webSocketSettings transportUsage="Always" createNotificationOnConnection="true" keepAliveInterval="00:00:30"  />
      </httpsTransport>          
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```